# Vector Field in Metapost

Tags: pgfplots, plot, asymptote, metapost

I would like to recreate [this graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4301996/691503) in Latex, but I saw it complicated so I was inclined to do it in [Metapost](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/):

```
s:=1.5cm ;

vardef u(expr x,y) = (y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x)) enddef ;
vardef v(expr x,y) = (-2*x*(1+y)) enddef ;

path tmparr ;
for x = -3.5 step 0.3 until 3.5 :
    for y = -3.5 step 0.3 until 3.5 :
        if ((x,y) = (0,0)):
        else:
            tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(x,y), v(x,y))) scaled 0.28s ;
            tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
            drawarrow  tmparr shifted ((x,y) scaled s) withcolor 0.37white;
        fi;
    endfor ;
endfor ;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Any idea how to graph the parabola `y=1-2*x*x`and the line `y=-1`?

If someone besides Metapost does it in Latex, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New:** There are 3 kinds of phase portraits: slope field, direction field, vector field. In this situation, I choose direction field with normalized length of the vectors (in my taste ^^, that is `.1*unit(...)` below).

```
path vector(pair z) {return .1*unit((f(z.x,z.y),g(z.x,z.y)));}
```

More: a clipping in the chosen box allows filling invariant domain as OP's request.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(8cm);
import contour;
import graph;
real f(real x, real y) {return y+x*x-x*(y-1+2*x*x)/4;}
real g(real x, real y) {return -2x*(1+y);}
real p(real x) {return 1-2x^2;}
real a=3.5;
pair A=(-a,-a), B=(a,a);
guide[][] pf=contour(f,A,B, new real[] {0});
guide[][] pg=contour(g,A,B, new real[] {0});
path pp=graph(p,-2,2);

path invdomain=pp--(a,-a)--(a,-1)--(-a,-1)--(-a,-a)--cycle;
fill(invdomain,yellow);

// set up the vector of the vector field
path vector(pair z) {return .1*unit((f(z.x,z.y),g(z.x,z.y)));}
// set up the condition for the vector will be drawn
bool cond(pair z) {
if (g(z.x,z.y)==0) {return false;}   
else {return true;}  
}
add(vectorfield(vector,A,B,28,cond,paleblue,Arrow()));

draw(pf[0],blue);
draw(pg[0],magenta);
draw(pp,magenta);

clip(box(A,B));
xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

**Old:** An Asymptote way: graph/contour/level curve of an implicit function, vectors in a vector field (with a condition).

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(8cm);
import contour;
import graph;
real f(real x, real y) {return y+x*x-x*(y-1+2*x*x)/4;}
real g(real x, real y) {return -2x*(1+y);}
real a=3.5;
pair A=(-a,-a), B=(a,a);

guide[][] pf=contour(f,A,B, new real[] {0});
guide[][] pg=contour(g,A,B, new real[] {0});

// set up the vector of the vector field
path vector(pair z) {return (f(z.x,z.y),g(z.x,z.y));}

// set up the condition for the vector will be drawn
bool cond(pair z) {
if (g(z.x,z.y)==0) {return false;}   
else {return true;}  
}

add(vectorfield(vector,A,B,20,cond,blue,Arrow()));

draw(pf[0],orange);
draw(pg[0],magenta);

//xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
//yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: I don't know why OP want to remove the bounding box ^^

Comment: Regarding the contour, it was only to know how it can be done for future graphics, Thank you very much, your answer is excellent! What command could paint the region between `f` and `y=-1`? Later I will post how the answer has finally turned out with your very useful help, now I can't put it in a comment because it is too long.

Comment: @Zaragosa In my opinion, direction field is more appropriate choice to visualize for this system of ODEs. Please check my new update!

Comment: Yeah thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to do but I didn't know how to do it so I put `path vector(pair z) {return ((f(z.x,z.y))/((f(z.x,z.y)f(z.x,z.y) +g(z.x,z.y)*g(z.x,z.y))^0.5),(g(z.x,z.y))/((f(z.x,z.y)*f(z.x,z.y)+g(z.x,z.y) *g(z.x,z.y))^0.5));}` But on the other hand I would like how to paint a trapped region between two functions because in reality I not only want to see the behavior but I want to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, to this should show a positively invariant region (that's why I insist).

Comment: @Zaragosa filling invariant regions is independent and easy task, see my revision

Comment: Thank you! A great answer

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but you could do the following using Metapost:

```
s := 1.5cm ;

vardef u(expr x,y) = (y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x)) enddef ;
vardef v(expr x,y) = (-2*x*(1+y)) enddef ;

path tmparr ;
for x = -3.5 step 0.3 until 3.5 :
    for y = -3.5 step 0.3 until 3.5 :
        if ((x,y) = (0,0)):
        else:
            tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(x,y), v(x,y))) scaled 0.28s ;
            tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
            drawarrow tmparr shifted ((x,y) scaled s) withcolor 0.37white;
        fi;
    endfor ;
endfor ;


% parabola

vardef f(expr x) = (1-2*x*x) enddef ;

path tmppara ; 
tmppara = (-1.5, f(-1.5)) for x = -1.5 step 0.01 until 1.5: .. (x, f(x)) endfor ;
draw tmppara scaled s withcolor red ;


% line

draw (-3.5,-1) scaled s -- (3.5,-1) scaled s withcolor red ;
```

[image]

---

An approach using PGFplots would be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-3.5:3.5, ymin=-3.5, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3 [quiver={
        u={(y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))/
            veclen(-2*x*(1+y), y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))}, 
        v={(-2*x*(1+y))/
            veclen(-2*x*(1+y), y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))}, 
        scale arrows=0.28
    }, -stealth, samples=20] {0};
\addplot [smooth, red] {1-2*x*x};
\addplot [smooth, red] {-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure whether the parabola and line are right and probably the quiver arrows need some adjustment ...

---

It may not be necessary in this case, but to plot implicit functions in general, you can use the `gnuplot` mechanism of PGF (maybe have a look around this site for more examples):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-3.5:3.5, ymin=-3.5, ymax=3.5, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3 [quiver={
        u={(y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))/
            veclen(-2*x*(1+y), y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))}, 
        v={(-2*x*(1+y))/
            veclen(-2*x*(1+y), y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x))}, 
        scale arrows=0.28
    }, -stealth, samples=20] {0};
\addplot [smooth, red] {1-2*x*x};
\addplot [smooth, red] {-1};

\addplot3 [raw gnuplot, smooth, blue] gnuplot {
      set contour base;
      set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
      unset surface;
      splot y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x);
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for Metapost, I have to admit that I am unsure whether plotting of implicit functions is easily possible without parametrization.

Comment: One question, how can I graph an implicitly defined function? I want to graph `y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x)=0` and `-2*x*(1+y)=0` in both metapost and PGFplots.

Comment: @Zaragosa I enhanced my answer, but as for Metapost, you should probably ask a new question. It seems that `-2*x*(1+y)=0` is essentially `y = -1`, so this is easily plottable.

Comment: Asymptote (a full extension of Metapost) can draw implicit graphs, try on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
`size(8cm);
import contour;
import graph;
real f(real x, real y) { return -2*x*(1+y);}
real g(real x, real y) { return y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x);}
real a=2.4;
pair A=(-a,-a), B=(a,a);
guide[][] pf=contour(f,A,B, new real[] {0});
guide[][] pg=contour(g,A,B, new real[] {0});
draw(pf[0],orange);
draw(pg[0],blue);

xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));`

Comment: @BlackMild Thank you very much!!! One query, can you graph the field `F(x,y)=(y+x*x-0.25*x*(y-1+2*x*x), -2*x*(1+y))` in Asymptote? I ask because this would also complete my question and would be very interesting. Is it possible to remove the bounding box from the graph?